# Ordering an Axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
dataToPlot = data.frame(
  Date = as.POSIXct(JMFINNTradingData$Transact.Time, format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS"),
  RollingPositionValues = JMFINNTradingData$SubTotal)

library('ggplot2')
myPlot = ggplot(dataToPlot, aes(y = dataToPlot$RollingPositionValues, x = dataToPlot$Date, group = 1))
myPlot + geom_line() + geom_path()
```

I have the following code with dates for the values of X and Numbers for the values of Y. For some reason the ordering of the Y axis is some random order and I cannot seem to influence this in any way. Image attached of how the Y axis looks like.

[image]

Comment: Your y variable is a factor.

Comment: `dataToPlot$RollingPositionValues <- as.numeric(as.character(dataToPlot$RollingPositionValues))`

Comment: you also dont need to use `$` inside this code `aes(y = RollingPositionValues, x = Date, ...)` should work

Comment: A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your values are probably `factors`. Convert them to numerics and it should plot correctly:

```
aes(y = as.numeric(as.character(dataToPlot$RollingPositionValues)), x = dataToPlot$Date, group = 1)
```

edit: Forgot to add `as.character()` when converting a factor to a numeric.

Comment: I tried this but the values this gives on the Y axis now is 0, 10 and 20. I am not sure how it came to this or how I can get rid of it.

Comment: `as.numeric` on a `factor` will get you the levels number (try `as.numeric(factor(paste0(10:1, "")))`). you need to do `as.numeric(as.character(...))`

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps as.numeric(as.character( ... )) ?

Comment: Thanks but in doing that i make errors. Error in seq.default(from = best$lmin, to = best$lmax, by = best$lstep) : 
  'from' must be of length 1
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide us with `RollingPositionValues`.
Probably there is a character value somewhere in it, and you will need to remove the row containing it.

Comment: Hi Thanks. The values for Y are the one on the image above. I have taken away the blank value but the error still exists

Comment: Before you use it in ggplot, convert the `RollingPositionValues` column to a numeric:

    `df$RollingPositionValues <- as.numeric(as.character(RollingPositionValues))`

And the remove any rows with NA's using:

    `df <- df[complete.cases(df),]`